# How can I record my usb webcam to an mp4 format?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, video4linux

I have been trying for hours to record my USB webcam to a .mp4 file format. The only format that works is .avi right now. I am on a RPi using video4linux2.

This code does not work:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -framerate 30 -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 /home/pi/videos/output.mp4
```

When opening the file, it gives me an error in my video player. I also tried adding "-f mp4" but that does not work either. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Add `-vf format=yuv420p` output option: `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -vf format=yuv420p /home/pi/videos/output.mp4`

Comment: Still getting a corrupt file error in VLC. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is the exact error? Also show your ffmpeg command and the complete log.